# Why doesn't sidebar align correctly?

Tags: html, css

I have two questions on the code below:

1. Why don't the two right divs move up so they are more vertically aligned with the content div?
2. Why is the "far right side" div not all the way right?

CSS

```
.container {width:800px;}
* {border:1px solid black;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div>nav area</div>

<div style="width:500px;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>

<div style="float:right;width:100px;">
this is the side bar area
</div>
<div style="float:right;width:100px;">far right side</div>

<footer style="clear:both;">footer area</footer>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n5xq9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The order of floating elements matters.  Placing the two `<div>` elements that are `float: right` *above* your Lorem Ipsum content `<div>` will make all three align vertically.
2. When multiple elements `float: right`, the first of the two will be farthest to the right.  If you want their order swapped, reverse their order in the document.  If you want one to appear below the other, order the higher one first and set the other one to `clear: right;`

Answer (score 0):

Simply `float-left` all your elements :)

http://jsfiddle.net/n5xq9/4/

<sub>Note that I've also added some margin to the first one (dunno if needed) to replicate your demo and your wishes</sub>

- `Question 1.` Fixed :)
- `Question 2.` It's the way the browser reads your document, top-to-bottom, right? Now imagine, in my example all are **`float: left`** (so here's a Pseudo-code to understand):

```
<div1> Float it left
<div2> Float left that one too

Results in the expected:
|div1||div2|
DIV1 was the first one to be floated left
DIV2 was the second one, and has to accommodate in the available floats
```

The **exact same principle** is applied to **`float-right`** elements. Let's see why they swap positions:

```
<div1> Float it right
<div2> Float right that one too

Results instead in
|div2||div1| cause logically:
DIV1 was the first one to float right
DIV2 was the second one. It has to stay cool and adjust to the available float
```